# ERPConnect for SAP R/3 RFCs - is it any good?

Tags: .net, saprfc, sap-dotnet-connector, sap-r3

We are considering whether we should propose using [Theobald Software's](http://theobald-software.com/) [ERPConnector](http://www.theobald-software.com/cms/en/erpconnect.net/erpconnect.net-sap-und-.net-nahtlos-verb.html) tool to give our .NET code a way of talking to SAP RFC. Has anyone got any experience using these together?

Comment: I'm looking at this too - anyone care to answer that has any experience with it?  :o)

Answer (score 4):

I have not tried ERPConnector. I have, however, used `SAP .NET Connector 2.0`, provided by SAP (at no cost) to talk RFC with SAP.

In the project, I used it to:

- send IDOCs to SAP
- set up a server to receive IDOCs from SAP

This was straightforward using the SAP .NET Connector 2.0 software.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how IDOCS relate to RFCs. Are they comparable?

Comment: IDOCs are a plain text structured documents that SAP can read and write. They are sent over the RFC protocol. The SAP .NET Connector can do other things with SAP as well, check out the documentation and sample code.